# method $.get() in js get file other directory

Tags: javascript, php

I have two directory and file php inside per directory example :

1. `admin/file.php`
2. `admin/directory2/need_get_data_from_directory1_file.php`

`$.get(\'../file.php?id=\' + $(this).val()`

How to get id from directory1/file.php

I thing path ../ wrong. how to run it.

Thank alot.

Answer (score 0):

path should be `$.get(\'../directory1/file.php?id=\' + $(this).val()`

Comment: The question is **really** awkwardly-worded, but I *think* that other than the unnecessary backslashes (which are in the question, perhaps there's more the OP isn't showing), this is right. Could use better explanation, though (or indeed, any explanation at all). Teach to fish rather than give a fish.

Comment: Still, prefer not to post an answer until the issue is clear.